# UITextfield text in array will not change a label's text in another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitextfield

Please help. What am I doing wrong? textfield.text goes into one array and is suppose to change a label that belongs to another array.

I have multiple textfields. Im trying to save the text of each field to an array and then setAlpha to 0. Then I have an equal amount of labels that I want to change to the textfield's text. I have tried using mutable and immutable arrays. I keep getting errors.

I've tried multiple ways and its got to be something simply dumb I'm missing. I've greatly reduced these arrays just to post here.

```
_namesText = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:_nameLabel1.text, _nameLabel2.text, nil];

_names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:_nameLabel1, _nameLabel2, nil];

_nameInputs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:_p1NameTextField, _p2NameTextField, nil];

_playerNameText = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_p1NameTextField.text, _p2NameTextField.text, nil];

    enter code here
- (IBAction)enterNamesButton:(id)sender {
//These don't work.

    for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        [_names[i] setAlpha:1];
        NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[_nameInputs[i] text]];
        [_lastTry addObject:tempString];
    }
//Then tried this. This is after trying for 2.5 hours and different coding.
    for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        _namesText[i] = _lastTry[i];
        UILabel *cell = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        cell.text = _lastTry[i];
        //[[_namesText[i] textLabel] text] = @"Idiot";
        _namesText[i] = cell;
        NSLog(@"%@", _namesText[i]);

// This works (but bad practice) and I want to loop through arrays that each UI element belongs to instead of typing it all out.

//    _nameLabel1.text = _p1NameTextField.text;

//    _nameLabel2.text = _p2NameTextField.text;
```

I expect this to work but NOPE!!!!

Comment: If your code generates errors please show what they are. As is I am not sure how to read this block of code since it includes several different approaches, is incomplete (where is `_lastTry` defined?), and I have no idea what errors you encountered with each approach.

Comment: No need to give me a -1. This is my first time using this site and still trying to figure out how to post with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following:

Array _fromTextField is the textfield you want to copy from and set Alpha to 0
Array _toLabelField is the label you want the text to appear in
Array _toStoreStrings is where you keep all the strings, for later maybe ?

```
NSMutableArray *_fromTextField = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Put the Text Fields in Here
NSMutableArray *_toLabelField = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Put the Labels in Here
NSMutableArray *_toStoreStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

int count = 0;
int overRun = [_toLabelField count];

for (UITextField *tf in _fromTextField)
{
  tf.alpha = 0;
  NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:tf.text];
  [_toStoreStrings addObject:tempString];
  if (count < overRun) // Check just in case Array sizes not same
  {
    UILabel *lb = [_toLabelField ObjectAtIndex:count];
    lb.text = tempString;
  }
  else
    break;

  count++;
}
```

The issue your code faces is you have an array of NSObject.  The compiler has no idea they are UITextField or UILabel unless you cast them with (type_cast *) or point a new typed variable at them.  Hence the crashes you were seeing.

Comment: I already have my labels on the storyboard and they are setup as outlets. I put them in a mutable array and regular array but no change. I don't want to create new labels.

Comment: Also I have more than 5 textfields and labels that are being used. Everything is already assigned to arrays. 

_nameLabel1.text = _p1NameTextField.text; is what I want to do via a loop where it goes:

_names[i] = _playerNameText[i];

nameLabel1.text is at index 0 in _names[]

_p1NameTextField.text is at index 0 in _playerNameText;

(would love to use the setText: method right now and semicolons are apparently replacing my periods in english. lol).

Comment: Okay this code has stopped the crashing but now I need to get my labels to appear again.

Comment: K. labels are appearing again. I added lb.alpha = 1 right before the if block ends. Now Im just looking to see how the code works to send the alpha message to each label.

Comment: Im still trying to learn the fast enumeration of Obj-C but I can tell what your code is doing now. Guess I've learned fast enum more than I knew. Is there a regular enum version of this code using for (i, i<x, i++)? Or is this the only way since tf.text seems to be key to making it work.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        _namesText[i] = _lastTry[i];
}
```

I cannot see why this won't work... does it?

Comment: _lastTry was from something else earlier. It is a mutable array that is alloc and initialized for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        [_lastTry addObject:_playerNameText[i]];
        
        _namesText[i] = _lastTry[i];
    } I don't know how to use the enter button without it posting the comment

Comment: It causes a green breakpoint in the code. -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' But the array isn't empty!???!

Comment: Oh it seems that you have a problem in the init... Use this in viewDidLoad '_lastTry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];' ... It should fix this.


You can put a new line in the comment by pressing shift with enter ;)